# Store values returned from a method to a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods

I need the user to input a number of tests, then time in `hh:mm:ss` and then convert it to seconds (with a method) and store the values on a array.

Here is my attempt:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many tests were done?");
tests = sc.nextInt();
// 3 columns, for swimming,ciclism and running
int[][] valueTestSeconds = new int[tests][3];
for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < 3; j++) {
        System.out.println("Swimming");
        hN = sc.nextInt();  //hours
        mN = sc.nextInt();  //minutes
        sN = sc.nextInt();  //seconds
        //conversion from hh:mm:ss to seconds
        secondsConversion = conversionHms(hN, mN, sN);
        valueTestSeconds[i][j] = secondsConversion;

        System.out.println("Ciclism");
        hC = sc.nextInt();
        mC = sc.nextInt();
        sC = sc.nextInt();
        secondsConversion = conversionHms(hC, mC, sC);
        valueTestSeconds[i][j] = secondsConversion;

        System.out.println("Running");
        hCo = sc.nextInt();
        mCo = sc.nextInt();
        sCo = sc.nextInt();
        secondsConversion = conversionHms(hCo, mCo, sCo);
        valueTestSeconds[i][j] = secondsConversion;
    }
}
```

```java
public static int conversionHms(int h, int m, int s) {
    int secondsC = (h * 3600) + (m * 60) + s;
    return secondsC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some duplicate code in the nested loop causes overwriting the elements in the array, and this code may be simplified:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("How many tests were done?");
int tests = sc.nextInt();
int[][] valueTestSeconds = new int[tests][3]; // 3 columns, for swimming, cycling and running
String[] sports = {
    "Swimming", "Cycling", "Running"
};

for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
    System.out.println("Test #" + (i + 1));
    for (int j = 0; i < 3; j++) {
        System.out.println(sports[j]);
        
        int h = sc.nextInt();  //hours
        int m = sc.nextInt();  //minutes
        int s = sc.nextInt();  //seconds
        valueTestSeconds[i][j] = conversionHms(h, m, s);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static int conversionHms(int h, int m, int s) {
    return h * 3600 + m * 60 + s;
}
```